# Allow html in product titles

Tags: magento2, product, title

so  here is the scenerio.

I want to display bare html in the product titles. But magento strips any html in the product title as you can see here (https://swadeshiherbal.com/khomba-baby-cologne-herbal-100ml-6.html) .

Please help me to find the template file that magento uses to display these titles so that I can remove any html escaping functions from there.

I tried to find the function but couldn't find it. however the below file contained a function call like so

public_html/app/code/Magiccart/Alothemes/Controller/Product/View.php

```
 $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
```

but it doesn't have any escaping functions

pleaese help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command to show the template path. You have to run this command in magento root:

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
```

Also if you are in **developer mode** then you can enable template hints from admin as well:

```
Go to Admin Panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug.
```

You can find exact path of any template and class.

Comment: thanks sire, much appreciated your input